# Conditional inside foreach inside conditional with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, syntax, razor, conditional-statements

I'm trying to learn Razor but have come up against a syntax problem.  When I run the following code:

```
@if (searchTerm != ""){
  <h2>Showing @ExamineManager.Instance.Search(searchTerm, true).Count() results for @searchTerm</h2>
  <div class="search-results">
    @foreach (var result in ExamineManager.Instance.Search(searchTerm, true)) {   
      if (result.Fields["nodeTypeAlias"] == 'File'){
        <p>File</p>
      }else{
        <p>Not file</p>  
      }
    }
  </div>
}
```

this errors, saying "Too many characters in character literal".  The actual mechanism of the code works, it's just a syntax problem with the way the conditionals are nested I think, but I've tried various combinations of @{} blocks and prepending @ to various lines but just can't get it to work.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you've got comparison

```
result.Fields["nodeTypeAlias"] == 'File'
```

In c#, you cannot write strings into single quotes like that. You should change it into

```
result.Fields["nodeTypeAlias"] == "File"
```

Comment: Ah-ha!  I've spend too much time with JavaScript recently, clearly ;)  This works perfectly now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`'File'` is invalid syntax. You probably meant `"File"` in your `if` condition when you want to work with strings:

```
if (result.Fields["nodeTypeAlias"] == "File")
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the Code In this way

```
    @{

      if (searchTerm != ""){
      <h2>Showing @ExamineManager.Instance.Search(searchTerm, true).Count() results for @searchTerm</h2>
      <div class="search-results">
        foreach (var result in ExamineManager.Instance.Search(searchTerm, true)) {   
          if (result.Fields["nodeTypeAlias"] == 'File'){
            <p>File</p>
          }
          else{
            <p>Not file</p>  
          }
        }
      </div>
    }


        }
```

THis code will help you

Comment: This equivalent to the original code, it's just some more spaghetti added to it.